# How can I create a tuple from a string that almost looks like a tuple but contains unquoted text?

Tags: python

My input data contains strings that look like this `( 'label',  ( 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 ) )` but also some like this `( 'label', #75, #174, #196 )`. The former can be converted to a tuple using `ast.literal_eval()` but the latter fails because the #xyz entries are neither numbers nor strings.

I would like to either modify the input string to place quotes around each #xyz entry so that `ast.literal_eval()` will work, i.e. `( 'label', '#75', '#174', '#196' )`, or use another function that assumes anything that is not a number is a string, quotes or not.

Comment: where do the strings come from? better to fix this problem upstream rather than some dirty parsing now

Comment: The strings come from the AP214 spec for the STEP 3D format and changing them isn't an option. I'm sure the ISO guys had a reason they did it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to either modify the input string to place quotes around
>   each #xyz entry so that ast.literal_eval() will work, i.e. ( 'label',
>   '#75', '#174', '#196' )

Use `re.sub` to replace #N with number inside quotes:

```
>>> a = "( 'label', #75, #174, #196 )"
>>> a
"( 'label', #75, #174, #196 )"
>>> re.sub(r"#(\d+)", r"'#\1'", a)
"( 'label', '#75', '#174', '#196' )"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a recursive function to build a tuple from values between commas taking into account the parenthesis groupings:

For example:

```
s1 = "( 'label',  ( 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 ) )"
s2 = "( 'label', #75, #174, #196, 37 )"

def str2Tuple(s):
    if "(" not in s and "," not in s:
        try :   value = int(s) if s.isdigit() else float(s)
        except: value = s.strip("'")
        return value
    result      = []
    group,value = 0,""
    for c in s+",":
        if c == "," and group == 0:
            result.append(str2Tuple(value.strip()))
            value = "";continue
        group -= c==")"
        if group>0 or c not in "()": value += c
        group += c=="("
    return tuple(result) if len(result)>1 else result[0]

print(str2Tuple(s1)) # ('label', (1.0, 2.0, 3.0))
print(str2Tuple(s2)) # ('label', '#75', '#174', '#196', 37)
```